# Spring Boot - reading a CSV file at a URI and return it as JSON

Tags: json, spring, csv

I am trying to write a Spring Boot app that is going to do the following:

On GET request to Main Controller /all, it needs to produce a request to a specific URI (http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-monthly-update-new-version.csv) and this will trigger a CSV file download. 
After that, it needs to read this file automatically, convert it to JSON and display it in a JSON format.

Any advice on the right approach I can use to solve this?

Comment: you'd (almost only) need to "name the columns" ...the structure can be assumed "stable"? ...but it 'd be a cool thing for "any kind of csv" :)

Comment: Does the file needs to go through a Db or there's a way to point Spring Boot to download it to a resource folder and read it from there with Jackson and Jackson-dataformat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/all")
public class MainController {
    private static final String URL = "http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-monthly-update-new-version.csv";

    @GetMapping
    public List<PricePaid> getDoc() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        List<PricePaid> pricePaidList = restTemplate.execute(URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, clientHttpResponse -> {
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(clientHttpResponse.getBody());
            CsvToBean<PricePaid> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<PricePaid>(reader)
                    .withType(PricePaid.class)
                    .withSeparator(',')
                    .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                    .build();
            return csvToBean.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        });

        return pricePaidList;
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm using `opencsv` library in order to parse the downloaded .csv and converting it into a list of `PricePaid` objects.

And also here is the `PricePaid` class:

```
public class PricePaid {
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String id;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private Integer price;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    private String dateOfTransfer;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 3)
    private String postCode;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 4)
    private String propertyType;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 5)
    private String oldNew;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 6)
    private String duration;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 7)
    private String paon;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 8)
    private String saon;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 9)
    private String street;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 10)
    private String locality;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 11)
    private String city;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 12)
    private String district;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 13)
    private String county;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 14)
    private String ppd;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 15)
    private String recordStatus;

    public PricePaid() {
    }

// getters and setters
}
```

Project can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/Ernyoke/price-paid-data

Comment: Thanks a lot, absolutely great stuff. Just out of curiosity, what would I need to tweak to get a certain line of a record by id? Or a group of records within a date range passed as a path variable?

Comment: @Bern All the records are stored in `List` named `pricePaidList`. Instead of returning that list, we can search for a single element in it and return that one. Or we can filter that list and return a subset from it.

Comment: Would you be so kind to show that in code? return a line that begins with the id we pass as a path variable and subset of lines between the date we pass as a path variable? thanks in advance

Comment: I would assume something like:  return csvToBean.stream()
               .filter(recordId -> recordId.getId()  == id)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: That is a fantastic and neat solution. Many thanks, matey!